# Trying to print a Queue as Array

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue

I am trying to print the contents of a queue as an array. I have the code working and compiling.  The problem is when I call the function more than once the print function does not call and the array is not printed again. I need to print the array more than once and it does not print.

The code for the Print function is :

```
template <class Type>
 void queueType<Type>::debugArray() 
 {
   for(queueFront; queueFront<count; queueFront++){
    cout << "[" << queueFront<< "] ," << list[queueFront] << " ";
   }

 } //end debugQueue
```

The main.cpp code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "queueAsArray.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    queueType<int> q1;
    queueType<int> q2;
    queueType<int> q3;
    int x = 5;

    for(int i= 0; i<10; i++) {
        q1.addQueue(i);
    }

    cout << "q1 after being filled up with 10 items" << endl;

    q1.printQueueInfo();

    cout << "Queue contents from front to rear\n\n" << endl;

    q1.debugArray();
    q1.deleteQueue();
    q1.deleteQueue();
    q1.deleteQueue();

    for(int i= 0; i<=20; i){
        i+=5;
        q1.addQueue(i);
    }

    q1.debugArray();
    return 0;
}
```

**Is there a reason why the function call will not print again**?  If you need the entire class and implementation file I can supply it. The weird thing is if I create a second instatiation of the class `q2`, then build an array for `q2`, the `debugQueue` function prints that queue. I then call the overloaded assignment operator and do `q2=q1`, then call `debugQueue` Again and it prints the contents of the queue.  So I am confused as why it will print the second queue twice, but not the first queue.
Any thoughts?

Comment: queueFront is a member variable that points to the first element of the queue, I can post the entire class file if there needs to be clarification

Comment: why are you changing it when printing?

Comment: I made a goofball mistake, I glossed over that issue.  When I originally wrote it I had an int named temp in its palce, but while correcting all the issues, I removed the temp int and forgot to change it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that you're mutating the `queueType` instance as a part of the printing.

```
template <class Type>
void queueType<Type>::debugArray() 
{
  for(queueFront; queueFront<count; queueFront++){
    cout<<"[" << queueFront<<"] ,"<< list[queueFront]<<" ";}
}
```

Here you are taking the member `queueFront` and mutating it forward until you hit the end of the queue.  This is mutating the field `queueFront` instead of a local which points to the same location.  Try using a local and it will fix your problem

```
for(auto current = queueFront; current < count; current++){
  cout<<"[" << current<<"] ,"<< list[current]<<" ";}
}
```

Note: I used `auto` for the type because I didn't know the type of `queueFront`.  I assume it's `list<int>::iterator` but wasn't sure.  You can replace `auto` with the correct type or leave it as is and let the compiler infer the type of `current`

Comment: @Craig the keyword `auto` in modern C++ compilers is a cue for type inference. It lets the compiler pick the type of the local based on the type of the expression which initialized it's value.  You can replace it with the type of `queueFront` I just didn't know what it was (assuming `list<int>::iterator` though)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just that you're changing `queueFront` permanently when you call `debugArray()`. You should probably just create a temporary... whatever it is and make sure `queueFront` is `const`, because the front of the queue shouldn't change (if that's what it's referring to).